# Audio pulseaudio / pipewire stopped working after i paused / stopped media with sound ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, google-chrome, alsa

software version:

1. pulseaudio 15.99.1 , pulseaudio 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.1
2. pipewire-alsa:amd64 0.3.76-1~ubuntu22.04
3. alsa-base 1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu7

Audio pulseaudio / pipewire stopped working after i paused/stopped media with sound at multimedia softwares (google chrome, vlc, etc). My workaround options to get the audio working again:

1. Keep playing media with sound, even with very low volume
2. kill pa with `pulseaudio -k`

I noticed some unfamiliar error at syslog, that states `pa_operation is nullptr`.

```
syslog:197779:Aug  9 12:47:54 userr google-chrome.desktop[9106]: [9819:9819:0809/124754.352932:ERROR:pulse_util.cc(351)] pa_operation is nullptr.
syslog:197780:Aug  9 12:47:54 userr google-chrome.desktop[9106]: [9819:9819:0809/124754.352950:ERROR:pulse_util.cc(351)] pa_operation is nullptr.
syslog:197781:Aug  9 12:47:54 userr google-chrome.desktop[9106]: [9819:9819:0809/124754.354840:ERROR:pulse_util.cc(351)] pa_operation is nullptr.
syslog:197782:Aug  9 12:47:56 userr google-chrome.desktop[9106]: [9819:9819:0809/124756.229540:ERROR:pulse_util.cc(351)] pa_operation is nullptr.
syslog:197783:Aug  9 12:47:56 userr google-chrome.desktop[9106]: [9819:9819:0809/124756.229595:ERROR:pulse_util.cc(351)] pa_operation is nullptr.
syslog:197892:Aug  9 12:48:54 userr google-chrome.desktop[9106]: [9819:9819:0809/124854.961184:ERROR:pulse_util.cc(351)] pa_operation is nullptr.
syslog:197893:Aug  9 12:48:54 userr google-chrome.desktop[9106]: [9819:9819:0809/124854.963137:ERROR:pulse_util.cc(351)] pa_operation is nullptr.
syslog:197959:Aug  9 12:49:57 userr google-chrome.desktop[9106]: [9819:9819:0809/124957.686568:ERROR:pulse_util.cc(351)] pa_operation is nullptr.
syslog:199694:Aug  9 13:16:05 userr google-chrome.desktop[9106]: [9819:9819:0809/131605.427928:ERROR:pulse_util.cc(351)] pa_operation is nullptr.
syslog:199695:Aug  9 13:16:05 userr google-chrome.desktop[9106]: [9819:9819:0809/131605.427980:ERROR:pulse_util.cc(351)] pa_operation is nullptr.
```

I find this audio problem since 1-2 weeks ago. I reinstalled pulseaudio, alsa and pipewire previously. I got it working after days, but the problem keep rising.

What caused this error? How to fix this permanently?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to look at the `/var/log/syslog`, and i found pulseaudio errors. Based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114602/pulseaudio-sink-always-suspended#171925), the main reason is the enabled `module-suspend-on-idle` at the `/etc/pulse/default.pa` config file. Commenting the line of the configuration solve the problem.

```
### Automatically suspend sinks/sources that become idle for too long
# load-module module-suspend-on-idle ## comment this line
```